# Drag and drop picture upload dropping a URL (not a file)

Tags: javascript, url, drag-and-drop

I would like to achieve the following:

Imagine there are two browser windows open, one (a) with a website that has a drop area for pictures files, the other one (b) with some pictures.

I want to be able to drag and drop a picture from (b) to the drop area of (a) and (a) should download and store the picture (without me first downloading the picture from (b) to my computer and then dropping the file in the drop area of (a).

I am not sure how I would even start this in JS. Any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to copy the url (with some metadata to identify where the clipboard content comes from) from the first browser and then paste it to the second. This might help on how to copy/paste with Javascript: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2014/12/02/definitive-guide-copying-pasting-javascript/ (and you'll need to mix that with the Drag and drop API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a multistep operation that could be done many different ways. 
Here are the outlines to a basic solution (using jQuery).

**Prevent Browser Default Behavior**

Many browsers will automatically replace the url of the current window/tab with the url of the content you are dragging, which refreshes the page. This isn't behavior you want, so the first step is to stop these events.

```
window.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
},false);
window.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
},false);
```

**Get URL of Image**

Create an `img` without a `src` as well as a dropzone area and start listening for `drop` events on your dropzone. When an image is dropped here, retrieve it's URL using `DataTransfer` (read more about DataTransfer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/getData)). Set the `src` of your empty `img` to the URL you just retrieved.

```
$('#dropzone').on('drop', function(e) {
    var url = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('url');
    $('#result').attr("src",url);
});
```

**Save Image**

Automating the saving of an image to your computer through Javascript is a trickier subject, but thankfully people have created various workaround solutions. I would recommend implementing [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) or something similar. To save an image using FileSaver.js however you will need to convert the `img` to a blob or canvas object first, which you can read about [here](https://davidwalsh.name/convert-canvas-image).

**EXAMPLE (no saving)**

```js
window.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);
window.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
  e = e || event;
  e.preventDefault();
}, false);

$('#dropzone')
  .on('drop', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('url');
    $('#result').attr("src", url);
  });
```

```css
#dropzone {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
}
#result {
  margin: 10px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dropzone">Drop Here</div>
<img id="result" />
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this excellent answer. It gave me lots of inspiration how to achieve this!

Comment: @ArminHierstetter you are welcome! If this answered your questions you can use the checkmark underneath the voting arrows to mark it as "accepted".